# Sentiment Analysis using classification and clustering algorithms: Which is better?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cluster-analysis, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to do a Sentiment Analysis on Song Lyrics using Python. 
After studying many simple classification problems, with known labels (such as Email classification Spam/Not Spam), I thought that the Lyrics Sentiment Analysis lies on the Classification field.
While actually coding it, i discovered that I had to compute the sentiment for each song's lyrics, and probably adding a column to the original dataset, marking it positive or negative, or using the actual sentiment score.

Couldn't this be done using a clustering approach? Since we don't know each song's class in the first place (positive sentiment / negative sentiment) the algorithm will cluster the data using sentiment analysis.

Comment: 1. If you do not have labels, then you are left with no choice but clustering
2. you can use cosine similarity approach to cluster similar songs together
3. how well this approach works will depend on your dataset and other pre processing steps-like tokenization etc.. Btw which dataset are you using

Comment: I am using this dataset.

https://www.kaggle.com/mousehead/songlyrics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clustering usually won't produce sentiments.

It a more likely to produce e.g., a cluster for rap and one for non-rap. Or one for lyrics with an even song length, and one for odd length.

There is more in the data than sentiment. So why would clustering produce sentiment clusters?

If you want particular labels (positive sentiment, negative sentiment) then you *need* to provide training data and use a supervised approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of Clustering without supervision i.e, unsupervised clustering which might result in low accuracy results because you actually dont know what is the threshold value of score which seperates the positive and negative classes.So first try to find the threshold which will be your parameter which seperates your classes.Use supervised learning to find the threshold

Comment: I was thinking to use a default threshhold, so i can screen and force the 2 classes, something like semi-supervised learning. The algorithm, knows that there are two classes, but it doesn't know which object belong to which class.

Sorry if I confuse you, i can elaborate more if you want

Comment: If you are using a default threshold then it is no longer called learning.You are trying to use a rule based approach if you are using a threshold.If you want to use supervised learning, then you let the algorithm to decide the threshold using the training data and then classify your test data according to your threshold obtained